# vb.net: Tab Delimited text file import to access database

Tags: vb.net, csv

Can somebody tell me why my code does not import Tab Delimited text file but works for comma Delimited text files and how can i make it work for Tab Delim files?

Code is as below

```
    Private Sub btnSelectFile_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSelectFile.Click

    Dim AccessConn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source= (Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source= C:\Users\Me\Documents\ShipmentDB.accdb;")

    Dim FileName As String
    Dim FilePath As String
    Dim TargetPath As String
    Dim FilePathLength As Integer = 0

    'Get Text File Location that user need to import (AskForFile is a OpenDialogBox)

    AskForFile.Reset()
    AskForFile.Title = "Select File you want To inport"
    AskForFile.Filter = "Text File|*.txt|All Files|*.*"
    AskForFile.Multiselect = False
    AskForFile.InitialDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments)
    AskForFile.ShowDialog()

    FileName = AskForFile.SafeFileName.ToString
    TargetPath = AskForFile.FileName.ToString
    FilePathLength = Len(TargetPath) - Len(FileName)

    FilePath = TargetPath.Substring(0, FilePathLength)

    Try
        AccessConn.Open()

        Dim DeleteTable As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand("DROP TABLE AmazonData;", AccessConn)
        DeleteTable.ExecuteNonQuery()

        Dim AccessCommand As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand("SELECT *  INTO AmazonData FROM [Text;DATABASE=" & FilePath & "].[" & FileName & "]", AccessConn)
        AccessCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()

    Catch ex As Exception
        AccessConn.Close()
        MessageBox.Show("Error Occured")
        Exit Sub
    End Try

    MessageBox.Show("Process Complete. Check and verify the database")

    AccessConn.Close()

End Sub
```

Comment: You may need to create a `schema.ini` file as described here: https://bytes.com/topic/access/answers/897728-how-set-delimiter-when-importing-text-source

Answer (score 0):

You should note that you are dropping the table, instead of deleting the data.
Try "delete from AmazonData" instead of "DROP TABLE AmazonData" in your first command.

Comment: I had to delete that table, Otherwise it will give me an Error " Table already exist" during "AccessCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()" execution.

Comment: Your second query is looks wrong also.
It should be something like "Insert into AmazonData select * from" ...